# Buffer Overflow - why some ascii's work and not others

Tags: c, overflow, buffer, exploit

I'm sorry if this question is stupid or has been asked, but I couldn't find it.

I have a program that I was attempting to use a buffer over flow.  It is a simple program that uses getchar() to retrieve the input from the user.  The buffer is set to size 12.  I can get the program to crash by typing >12 x's or using >12 \x78's, but it won't seg fault if I type in hundreds of A's or \x41's.

Any help or pointing in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post your whole program.

Comment: If you overwrite memory, there is always one chance in 256 that the byte doesn't change it's value.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't post the code.  If this is too general a question without the code, I guess please ignore it.  Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 0):

0x41414141 may be a valid address within a text page of the process. Look at the segment map of the process for details.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but I ran gdb with the 100 A's and it didn't write over the local variable above buffer[11] and it acted as though the program ran perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate guessing, look at the assembly code and then at machine instructions of your program. Run it in a debugger and see what happens in the memory. You can see at what addresses on the stack local variables are placed and and what addresses registers and especially the instruction pointer are saved on a function call.

Have you look at examples like [the stack overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow) on Wikipedia?

Comment: I did look at that, which is why I tried all A's.  It seems like any input larger than the buffer should overwrite the next thing, but I guess not.  I did run through the objdump -d and walked through gdb running the program so I know the memory layout, it goes the stack then a counter i then two addresses then the saved ebp then the return address.